# Laravel on AWS ElasticBeanstalk: running artisan migration command on deployment using .ebextensions in failing

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying the Laravel application to the ElasticBeanstalk. I am running migration command using .ebextensions config on deployment.

I created a .extensions/01-migration.config file under the project root folder with the following content.

```
container_commands:
  01_cd_html:
    command: "cd /var/www/html"
  02_php_artisan_migrate:
    command: "php artisan migrate --force"
```

Then I deploy my application by running the following command.

```
eb deploy
```

Then I got the following error.

```
2020-07-13 11:51:59    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2020-07-13 11:52:39    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2020-07-13 11:52:49    ERROR   [Instance: i-0a461ffb24bc26f52] Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].
2020-07-13 11:52:49    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2020-07-13 11:52:49    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0a461ffb24bc26f52'. Aborting the operation.
2020-07-13 11:52:50    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

I could SSH into the server and run the command successfully. But it is just not working on deployment. What is wrong with my configuration and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you inspect the EB logs to locate more detailed error message?

Comment: Can you please try deploying a simple one page PHP application into EBS. See whether the PHP versions are same for Laravel app and the demo PHP app. Also see whether this version is supported by EBS. If the PHP version is not supported, you have to Dockerize it and do a deployment

Comment: Hi, I found the issue. I need to set the environment variables required by the commands in the option settings. That is weird. It should also grab from the ones from Beanstalk environment console too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. I need to set the environment variables required by the commands in the option_settings. The command I am trying to run is migration command and it is using database credentials. So I specified the env variables for the database. That is weird, it should just work with ones specified in the ElasticBeanstalk console.

Comment: Can you share how to add environment variables to the .ebextensions files?